# Changing a tcolorbox listing option based on the number of lines of its listing

Tags: listings, environments, tcolorbox, counters, programming

Consider the following code which produces listings:

```
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Preamble
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Packages
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{printlen}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Length
\newlength{\evenlength}
\setlength{\evenlength}{0pt}
\newlength{\oddlength}
\setlength{\oddlength}{10pt}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Listing
\newtcblisting{lstbox}[4][\normalsize]{
    code = {},
    enhanced,
    listing only,
    top = 0pt,
    %%%%%%
    % I want bottom to be equal to:
    % - \evenlength if the listing has an even number of lines
    % - \oddlength if the listing has an even number of lines
    bottom = 0pt,
    %%%%%%
    left = 0pt,
    right = 0pt,
    arc = 0pt,
    outer arc = 0pt,
    boxsep = 0pt,
    titlerule = 0pt,
    colback = red,
    colframe = black,
    boxrule = 2pt,
    title = {\centering{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#2\strut}},
    listing options = {
        language = C++,
        framesep = 0pt,
        rulesep = 0pt,
        aboveskip = 0pt,
        belowskip = 0pt,
        backgroundcolor = \color{lightgray},
        basicstyle = \fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1,
        #3,
    },
    #4,
}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Document
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstbox}[\small]{title}{}{}
1
2
\end{lstbox}
\begin{lstbox}[\small]{title}{}{}
1
2
3
\end{lstbox}
\begin{lstbox}[\small]{title}{}{}
1
2
3
4
\end{lstbox}
\end{document}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
```

Would there be a way to make the `tcolorbox` `bottom` option equal to

- `\evenlength` when the listing has an even number of lines
- `\oddlength` when the listing has an odd number of lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your list of `\newtcblisting` options, add the following one

```
process code = {%
    \tcbset{ bottom = \ifodd\lst@lineno \oddlength \else \evenlength \fi }%
}
```

and wrap that command in `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`.

The code in `process code` will be executed in a hook used in `\end{lstbox}`. At that point the number of lines in the listing code is already know (last value of `\lst@lineno`), but the bottom hasn't been printed yet, so the `bottom` option can still be changed.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Does it also work if the firstnumber has been set to something different than 1? And if not, how to deal with it?

Comment: @Vincent Could you extend your samples to all the different use cases you want the solution to deal with?